# how to validate multiple textboxes on button click using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

In my application I have five textboxes.

When submit button click I want to validate these textboxes.

Validation should be at least 3 textboxes should have value in it.

Old way is using jQuery each loop we can check but is there any other way to do it ?

```js
$("#submitBtn").on("click", function(){
  var count = 0;
  $(".textboxesDiv input").each(function () {
    if($(this).val() != "" && $(this).val() != null && $(this).val() != undefined){
      count++;
    }
  });
  if(count > 2 )
  {
    alert("3 or more");
  }
  else{
    alert("lessa than 3");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="textboxesDiv">
  <input type="text" id="textbox1" >
  <input type="text" id="textbox2" >
  <input type="text" id="textbox3" >
  <input type="text" id="textbox4" >
  <input type="text" id="textbox5" >
</div>
<input type="submit" id ="submitBtn" name="button"/>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7Lmgbbng/1/

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: @A.Lau I was using Jquery each loop to do this.

Comment: Show us some code, how can we do, what to do, where to do, why to do ?

Comment: Please provide [mcve]

Comment: @Vaibhav you can get value of input box using its id or class and then you can validate your input box values

Comment: https://validatejs.org/

Comment: Anyway you have to loop through every input, in one way or another..  You can use a plugin or framework..  Or, you can use html5 for this if you don't care about old browsers, like in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12470712/863110) answer..

Comment: How about a counter and check values in each text box on submit and then increment that counter and then check if counter is less than 3.

Comment: I upvote because it is a good question but the style should be improved, please put an example.

Comment: take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41330280/2534646) hope it'll help

Comment: @MoshFeu see fiddle example. I have done something like this.

Comment: @wtx see this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/7Lmgbbng

Comment: Your code works, are you just asking for alternatives/cleaner code?

Comment: @vaibhavshah I don't think you could do better, unless html5 or plugin..

Comment: @A.Lau Is there any better way to do it ?

Comment: @MoshFeu Any example of html5 you can give ?

Comment: better way? not that I'm aware of. Different way? Filter might make it look cleaner. Or it might just end up the same. But I'm curious why you have this line `if($(this).val() != "" && $(this).val() != "" && $(this).val() != "")` the three comparison are all the same.

Comment: @A.Lau thst is just coding mistake, checking for null & undefined values as well. Updated fiddle

Comment: I added you the the comment. Here is again: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12470712/863110

Answer (score 0):

Check this example 
http://jsfiddle.net/ggChris/mfbaxkfp/

```
<input id="AccountText" type="text" name="AccountText" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required=''/>
<input class="button" type="submit" value="submit">


$(document).ready(function(){
       $('.button').click(function(){
            if ($('input#AccountText').val() == ""){
                alert('Please complete the field');
            }
        });
    });
```

or you can use jquery validation
 https://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: I haev multiple textboxes here

Comment: Use this below condition 
if ($('input#AccountText').val() == ""  || ($('input#AccountText2').val() == "" || ($('input#AccountText'2).val() == ""  )